# How to find out variance from array of numbers?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, math

New to Java here! I have to have the user enter 10 numbers and store them in an array (of doubles). After that I need to calculate:

**Mean:** I have that done and I need it to get the variance & std dev requires knowing the variance.

**Variance:** aka the average of the squares of the distance from the mean. The part I'm confused with. For each number in the array, I have to subtract the number from the mean, square the result, and then add the square to a running total. After that I have to divide the running total by the number of values (10).

Lastly, **Standard deviation:** aka the square root of the variance

I have to print all the results rounded to 2 decimal places.

Example: if my dataset was just {4, 7.5, 8}, then the mean is (4 + 7.5 + 8)/3 = 19.5/3 = 6.5.

Variance = ((6.5 - 4)^2 + (6.5 - 7.5)^2 + (6.5 - 8)^2
)/3 = (6.25 + 1 + 2.25)/3 = 9.5/3 = 3.17

Standard Deviation = √3.17 = 1.78

What I need help with is the math to find out the variance. I am not sure how to take a running total or how to square root numbers in parenthesis.

```
public class Statistics {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int userNumbers;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  // Creating Scanner object
    System.out.print("Enter the 10 numbers: ");
    userNumbers = scan.nextInt();

    double array[] = new double[userNumbers];
    double mean;
    double variance;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        userNumbers += userNumbers;
        mean = userNumbers / 10;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        variance = mean - userNumbers;

    }

    System.out.print("The variance is:" + );
    System.out.print("The standard deviation is: " + Math.sqrt(variance));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    variance = mean - userNumbers;
}
```

you are overwriting the value of `variance` in each iteration of the loop, so only the last value would be kept.

Also, for both loops, you want to use the elements in the `array`
Try adding to the value

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    variance += mean - array[i];
}
```

Comment: when I change it to that it mentions 'variance' and 'mean' haven't been initialized. What should I initialize them to?

Comment: How about `zero` ?

Comment: @codemonk12 If this answers your question, please consider to upvote and/or accept this answer